# How to use a LayoutInflater to inflate a layout with views pointing to a MutableContextWrapper?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-inflate, mutable-context-wrapper

I have a complex "floating view" hierarchy that I am moving between different activities. As these views are shared across activities, they should all have a `MutableContextWrapper` that will allow them to change the base context. In theory I can have multiple floating views simultaneously.

Here is an example XML for a floating view:

```
<com.test.views.SampleFloatingView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sample_floating_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.test.views.MinimizedImage
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

</com.test.views.SampleFloatingView>
```

I am inflating this XML using a `MutableContextWrapper` and add it to a FrameLayout that will hold it (so I can drag it across the screen), but I'n not getting the result I need:

```
@NonNull
private FrameLayout createSampleFloatingView() {
    MutableContextWrapper mutableContextWrapper = new MutableContextWrapper(getActivity());
    final FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(mutableContextWrapper);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mutableContextWrapper);
    View floatingView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_floating_view, null, true).findViewById(R.id.sample_floating_view);
    setViewMutableContext(floatingView);
    view.addView(floatingView);
    return view;
}

private void setViewMutableContext(View view) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    if (context instanceof MutableContextWrapper) {
        ((MutableContextWrapper) context).setBaseContext(getActivity());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("View " + view + " doesn't have a MutableContextWrapper");
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        int childCount = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            setViewMutableContext(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while the `FrameLayout` has a `MutableContextWrapper` the context of the inflated objects is the Activity which creates the view. This means that the code above crashes as `SampleFloatingView` doesn't have a `MutableContextWrapper`. If I remove this code a memory leak would later occur once I disconnect the view from the original activity and move it to the next.

An obvious solution to this issue would be to create the whole hierarchy manually and pass the `MutableContextWrapper` in the constructor (like I do for the `FrameLayout`), but I rather avoid it for obvious reasons.

My question is whether there is a better way that will allow me to **inflate  views from XML and force their context to point to a `MutableContextWrapper`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for the issue I saw was the way the default LayoutInflater works (the one you get from `LayoutInflater.from(context)`). It uses the last activity to inflate the views and that was the reason I got the undesired result. I can't say I too thrilled with the solution, but it seems to be working. What you have to do is to create a custom LayoutInflater and set its `Factory`. According to some documentations I read, the solution I used might have compatibility issues in case you are using support/compat views, but I assume you can go around those issues as well in case you encounter it.

Here is the code for the custom `Factory` & `LayoutInflater` classes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static class MyLayoutInflaterFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory2 {

    private static final Class<?>[] constructorSignature = new Class[] {Context.class, AttributeSet.class };

    final MutableContextWrapper mutableContextWrapper;

    public MyLayoutInflaterFactory(MutableContextWrapper mutableContextWrapper) {
        this.mutableContextWrapper = mutableContextWrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        Constructor<? extends View> constructor = null;
        Class<? extends View> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = mutableContextWrapper.getClassLoader().loadClass(name).asSubclass(View.class);
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor(constructorSignature);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return constructor.newInstance(mutableContextWrapper, attrs);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // Perhaps this can be done better
        return onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }
}

public static class MyLayoutInflater extends LayoutInflater {

    protected MyLayoutInflater(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
        return new MyLayoutInflater(newContext);
    }
}
```

And the way I use it to inflate my floating views:

```
@NonNull
private FrameLayout createSampleFloatingView() {
    MutableContextWrapper mutableContextWrapper = new MutableContextWrapper(getActivity());
    FrameLayout view = new FrameLayout(mutableContextWrapper);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = new MyLayoutInflater(mutableContextWrapper);
    LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(layoutInflater, new MyLayoutInflaterFactory(mutableContextWrapper));
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_floating_view, view, true);
    return view;
}
```